# Can anyone try how to solve the query for this table structure?

Tags: sql, t-sql

Employee table structure

```
first_name varchar2(100)
last_name  varchar2(100)
hire_date  date
```

show all the employee who hired on the day of the week on which highest number of employees were hired?

Comment: lol, WHAT? sry not making fun of anyone but this is hilarious the way it is asked?

Comment: So you want to find the weekday where the most employees were hired (eg: Friday) and find all the employees hired on this weekday? That's what I understand here.

Comment: Please write a meaningful title. Nobody can "try how to solve".

Comment: What is DB ? Oracle, I guess ?

Comment: @Stefan Steinegger - Jon Skeet could....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select first_name, last_name from employee 
where 
DAYNAME(hired_date) = (
select top 1 dow 
from (
select COUNT(first_name) as cnt, DAYNAME(hire_date) as dow 
from employee
group by (dow)
order by cnt desc
)
)
```

This is with mysql, but I am certain there are similar functions in db2, oracle, ms sql server, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
   select top 1 * from( 
    select count(first_name) as countemp from employee
    where hire_date between DATEADD(day,-7,getdate())
                        and  getdate()
 group by(hire_date)   ) d order by countemp desc
```

Comment: This doesn't work as it groups by date, not the day of the week.

Comment: isn't it selects only rows within the last week ?